# <f:facet name="filter"> not working in primefaces 3.5

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i use PF 3.5,i have 4 column filters:both filter's data are being filled fine.But date colunm ( ) does not work.

Comment: upgrade to a newer version? download the source of 3.5 and 5.3 and create your own patch? Otherwise I don't think it it possible if 3.5 does not support the facet

Comment: its been 2 months   working on my application , i cannot upgrade to a newer version

Comment: i want the user select date from the calendar to find data  and not type it manually

Comment: Regardless the amount of time you spend on it, regardless the requirement... it is not by some kind of magic suddenly going to be  possible... My first comment is not going to change...

Comment: <f:facet name="filter"> 
                  
                        <p:calendar   pattern="dd/MM/yyyy">
                            <p:ajax event="dateSelect" />
                        </p:calendar>
                        
                    </f:facet>-->    cannot be replaced by some code ?

Comment: What answer do you think I would give?

Comment: okey! if forget about the facet, how can I check if a string is a Date!( same prob in PF 3.5 load lazeDataModel does not implement Map<String, Object> filters :'(

Comment: problem solved, i eliminated the filter in date column -_-